# Prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2\geqslant\frac{1}{3}$ given that $a\gt0, b\gt0, c\gt0$ and $a+b+c=1$, using existing AM GM inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Using the AM and GM inequality, given that
$a\gt0, b\gt0, c\gt0$ and $a+b+c=1$ prove that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geqslant\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Using (a+b+c)^2 = 1 but I got stuck

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck with that attempt? What stopped you from progressing? And also, please edit your question post with this information as that makes it easier for new readers to catch up (they won't have to sift through comments).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knowing that for any set of real numbers $x,y,z$, such that $x+y+z = 1$ the inequality $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge \frac{1}{3}$ holds.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247973/knowing-that-for-any-set-of-real-numbers-x-y-z-such-that-xyz-1-the-ineq)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1572128/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2256206/42969 – all found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%5Cgeqslant%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR I've been looking for a tool like Approach0 for a while but didn't know where to find one. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Théophile: More Information here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969) and here: [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a^2+{1\over 9} + b^2+{1\over 9} + c^2+{1\over 9}\geq {2\over 3}(a+b+c)$$ by AM-GM.

Comment: I don't really understand how you obtained the result. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 6):

HINT: You can use your idea of squaring $a+b+c$, but also note that $\color{blue}{ab+bc+ca \le a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$, which you can prove with the help of AM-GM. (Hint for proving this: the AM-GM inequality tells us what about $a^2 + b^2, b^2+c^2$ and $c^2+a^2$?)

One more hint (based on a suggestion from user qsmy): let $x = a^2+b^2+c^2$ and $y = ab+bc+ca$. Squaring both sides of $a+b+c=1$ gives $x+2y=1$, and the blue inequality is $x\geq y$. Can you see it now?

Comment: I know the inequality that you stated, but I just can't seem to connect it with my question, please help. Thanks!

Comment: If you expand $1=(a+b+c)^2$, you should find $ab+bc+ca$ pop up. Apply the blue inequality above to this term.

Answer (score 3):

In the worst case possible you'd get $$a = b = c = \frac{1}{3} \Longrightarrow a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{9} = \frac{3}{9} \geq \frac{1}{3} $$

In the best case possible you'd get $$a = 1, b = c = 0 \Longrightarrow 1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1 \geq 1/3 $$

Therefore the inequality holds. Didn't use the AM-GM inequality, though.